# Using png or svg image as graphviz node

Tags: image, macos, svg, png, graphviz

I've tried to use a custom image node in graphviz (node `d`):

```
digraph foo {
    rankdir=LR;
    node [shape=record];
    a [label="{ <data> 12 | <ref>  }", width=1.2]
    b [label="{ <data> 99 | <ref>  }"];
    c [label="{ <data> 37 | <ref>  }"];
    d [image="X_Shape_Pillar_Yellow.png"];
    a:ref:c -> b:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false, arrowsize=1.2];
    b:ref:c -> c:data [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
    c:ref:c -> d      [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
}
```

Unfortunately, the image does not appear:

[image]

I've compiled the dot file using:

```
dot -v -Tpng list.dot -o list.png
```

My code, including the png image, [is stored in github](https://github.com/adamatan/graphviz_linked_list).

**How do I use a replace node `d` with my custom image?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply define an other shape for this node, for example `shape=none`:

```
d [shape=none, label="", image="X_Shape_Pillar_Yellow.png"];
```

The `record` shape defined as default does not display the image, whereas `none`, `box` and even `plaintext` do.

At the same time, it may be a good idea to set the label to nothing.

Comment: Works, thanks! https://github.com/adamatan/graphviz_linked_list/blob/master/list.png

Comment: the shape=none has to come before you set the image

Comment: I don't know if this solution works anymore. In the github link above it looks like the image is no longer added.