# Graphviz able to connect between images?

Tags: graph, graphviz, diagram, class-diagram

From what I see, graphviz is only to connect between text nodes. Is there any way which will be able to do the same but use images, instead of plain text nodes?

If graphviz is not capable of doing that, is there any other similar open source software that could help? E.g., Something like this, with square images instead of cycles.

[image: Demo image]

Comment: Of course you can [use images with graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15502651/63733)

Comment: @marapet Indeed... thank you for your comment!